# How to properly use the interval function?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have to do the following:

Rank users for persona = 'z'  with spends maximum to least in last week.

I have written the following code:

```
SELECT U.*, SUM(T.amount) AS total_spends
FROM User U
JOIN Transact T ON U.id = T.created_by
WHERE U.persona = 'Z' AND T.date_created >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week'
GROUP BY U.id
ORDER BY total_spends DESC;
```

But, I get the following error:
Error: near "'1 week'": syntax error

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the quotes around 1 week.

Comment: @Shadow I tried that. It now shows "Error: near "1": syntax error"

Comment: What about just using 7 days instead of a week?  INTERVAL 7 day ?

Comment: Also check this link out I think it will help you -->
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/

Comment: Here's a demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/Gu_BWXNa You can see it works fine to use `INTERVAL 1 WEEK`. I don't know what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT U.*, SUM(T.amount) AS total_spends
FROM User U
JOIN Transact T ON U.id = T.created_by
WHERE U.persona = 'Z' AND T.date_created >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY U.id
ORDER BY total_spends DESC;